# pass object method as function argument for method chaining in python

Tags: python, pandas

I know similar questions have been asked and answered but i could not find one that really solves my problem.

I want to pass an builtin pandas dataframe method as function argument to use it in a chained method call like the following:

```
def myFun(df,fun):
    df.fun().anotherfun()

myFun(df,'mean')
```

i tried it with builtin `getattr(df,fun)` but this did not work.

**EDIT**: my bad, i forgot to call it with `()` .
`getattr(df,fun)().anotherfun()` works perfectly

Comment: Methods ARE attributes and are looked up by the very same mechanism as other attributes so assuming that `df` is the dataframe and `fun` the name (as string) of a dataframe method, `getattr(df, fun)` should return the method object. Then you of course have to call it...   You states that "this obviously doesn't work" but forgot to mention HOW it "doesn't work" ("doesn't work" is actually the least useful description of a problem) so please edit your question to add the code you tried and the exact description of the result (traceback etc if you got an error).

Answer (score 3):

How about this? Is it what you are looking for?

```
def myFun(df,fun):
    getattr(df, fun)().anotherfun()
```

Comment: lol i assumed that when he said he'd tried it, that meant it _didn't_ work